# How to publish debug build of Azure Function to enable debugging?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

I'm trying to debug an Azure Function, but there doesn't appear to be a way of changing the Debug/Release mode from within the new Azure Functions tools in Visual Studio 2017.3.

How do I debug?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the vs2017 preview doesn't provide the way to directly change the publish setting.

I suggest you could find the publish profile and change its setting by yourself.

More details, you could follow below image:

1.Open the application folder

[image]

2.You could locate the profile file folder and find the publish profile.

```
\Properties\PublishProfiles
```

3.Open the profile and change the release to debug.

[image]

The result is like this:

[image]

Notice: To see the configuration changed, you need reopen the visual studio preview.